# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function on reactjs how to fix this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const items = this.state.events
  .filter((data) => {
    if (this.state.search == null) return data;
    else if (
         ...
         ...
    ) {
      return data;
    }
  })
  .map((data) => {
    return (
      <div>
            <span>{data.title}</span>
            <span>{data.description}</span>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

This is my function and i tried different ways of putting return but i still get the error **Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function.**

Can anyone help me fix this ?

Comment: That sounds like a linter warning, not something that React or JavaScript itself would produce. Are you using eslint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a valid return for every branch of logic

```
.filter((data) => {
  if (this.state.search == null) {
    return data; // <-- branch 1 good
  } else if (...) {
    return data; // <-- branch 2 good
  } // implicit else
  // <-- oops, branch 3 missing, add explicit return
  return true; 
})
```